# Try to put header in all text file in folder using textarea, please help me

Tags: java

trying to write code to put header in all the text files in folder and create output text file.. in different folder.. I wrote the code.. using textarea put header in it and using string actually its working the only thing is not working is when i put two or more lines in header i mean in textarea. so in output files print header all in one line.. please help me..

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;

public class header3 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // File folder = new File("Letters" + File.separator + "LettersIn");
        // System.out.println(folder);

        // System.out.println(BFFile);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Enter Header");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        final JTextArea text = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                BufferedReader br = null;

                BufferedWriter bfAll = null;

                File folder = new File("FileIn");

                File[] BFFile = folder.listFiles();

                // Caret header1 = text.getCaret();

                String header1 = (text.getText());
                System.out.println(header1);

                text.setLineWrap(true);
                text.setWrapStyleWord(true);

                try {

                    for (File file : BFFile) {

                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                        String filename = file.getName();
                        String[] fileInitialName = filename.split("\\.");

                        System.out.println(folder);

                        System.out.println(BFFile);

                        String outFileAllcount = ("FileOut" + File.separator
                                + "out" + fileInitialName[0] + ".txt");

                        bfAll = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                                outFileAllcount));

                        String line;

                        bfAll.write(header1.toString());
                        bfAll.newLine();

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            bfAll.write(line.toString());
                            bfAll.newLine();
                        }

                        bfAll.newLine();
                        bfAll.flush();
                        bfAll.close();

                        frame.dispose();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println("Excepton occured !! : "
                            + e1.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // String header1 = text.getText();

        // String header1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("here");

    }

}
```

Please help me!! If I put 2 or more line in textarea as header its work but print all in one line.. is there anyway to print all line as in textarea as a header in text file.. please let me know.. thanks.. if i put 10 line header it should be print 10 lines.. in files.. but it just print 1 line.. please help me!!
Thanks!!:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java code, Try to put header in all text file in folder using textarea, please help me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124727/java-code-try-to-put-header-in-all-text-file-in-folder-using-textarea-please-h)

Answer (score 1):

When you press **Enter** on your keyboard, Java adds a *new line* character as `\n`. So, `header1` variable contains only the `\n`. As you can see on your example, sometimes that is not enough (for example, Windows also needs a *carriage return* character).

So, just do this before you write `header1.toString()` to file, replace all *new line* characters (placed in by Java for the purpose of new line) with *system default* one:

```
header1= header1.replaceAll("\n", System.lineSeparator());
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand.. can you please tell me again..String header1 = (text.getText()); change this line??

Comment: `String header1 = text.getText().replaceAll("\n", System.lineSeparator());`

Comment: Thanks you so much i get it!!. Thanks for you time and help.. its just one line.. lol.. thanks again..